# Developing Laurent series for $\frac{e^{z}}{z}-z_{0}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I need to develop Laurent series for $\frac{e^{z}}{z}-z_{0}$.
**My attempt:** 
I have just developed a Taylor series for the exponent and got  :$\frac{1}{z}\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{z^{n}}{n!}-z_{0}$

But in the solution, they said we need to change $z$ into $z'=z-z_{0}$ and then to develop Taylor series to the exponent.

Whay my solution is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you are asked to find the Laurents series around $z_0$. What you have written is the Laurent series around $0$.

Answer (score 1):

More than surely, the problem is what Kavi Rama Murthy wrote in comment.

What they say in the solution is a very good trick : when you need a Taylor or Laurent series around $z=z_0$, start letting $z=x+z_0$ and work the expansion around $x=0$. This will save a lor of time and computation effort.

When finished, replace $x$ by $(z-z_0)$.

Just a small **hint** : for the coefficients in this problem, think about the complete and incomplete gamma functions.

**Edit**

To help you starting, as said, let $z=x+z_0$ to make
$$\frac{e^{z}}{z}-z_{0}=\frac{e^{z_0+x}}{z_0+x}-z_0=e^{z_0}\frac{e^{x}}{z_0+x}-z_0$$

Comment: I understood where the problem was, thank you. But I have tried to develop the series as you said and I still can't get an answer:$\frac{e^{z'+z_{0}}}{z'+z_{0}}-\left ( z'-z \right )= \frac{e^{z_{0}}}{z'+z_{0}}\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{z'^{n}}{n!}-z'+z$ how do I contine to develop the equation?